# Are the distances between .so sections always preserved, no matter where in memory the .so gets loaded?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, elf, dynamic-linking

*TLDR: The .so can't know where it will be loaded, but each segment must surely know where the other segments are, relative to itself?*

---

I have the following `.c` file:

```
int shared_variable = 3;

int shared_func()
{
    return shared_variable;
}
```

I compile it with PIC: `gcc -fpic -c -g shared.c` and `objdump` it, and see the GOT being used (line 1), as well as a relocation for the GOT entry (line 2), then finally the value of `shared_variable` is fetched (line 3):

```
8:  48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # f <shared_func+0xf>
        b: R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX   shared_variable-0x4
f:  8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
```

I then create a shared library: `gcc -shared -o libshared.so shared.o`, `objdump` that, and see that the relocation for the GOT entry has been resolved:

```
1101:   48 8b 05 d0 2e 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ed0]        # 3fd8 <shared_variable-0x48>
1108:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
```

So this code now assumes the GOT entry is at `0x2ed0` bytes from this part of the `.text` section. And indeed, if I run `readelf` I see that `.text` starts at `0x1040`, and `.got` starts at `0x3fd0`, `0x2f90` away. I also see that `.text` and `.got` are in different segments.

The `.so` can't know where in memory it will *actually* be loaded though, so I assume the addresses in `readelf`s section headers are just suggestions. But since the distance to the GOT entry (`mov rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ed0]`) is hard coded, I assume the *distances between* the segments of the `.so` will always be as specified in the program headers? It also feels sensible, since how would the code in the `.so` otherwise be able to find the GOT?

Comment: Be careful -- you seem to be confusing *segments* and *sections* -- they are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ChrisDodd! I tried to be careful about the use of "section" and "segment" above, what exactly seems to be my confusion? My understanding of this is that an ELF file contains a set of sections, which are grouped into a set of segments. When you look at `readelf -lS`, the Program Headers describe where each segment is supposed to be loaded, and the Section Headers describe in more detail where each specific section gets loaded. (You can also see the Section to Segment mapping for info about which sections go in which segment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a source for this. In Linkers and Loaders by John R. Levine, chapter 10.2:

> Because the GOT is in the same loadable ELF file as the code that references it, and **the relative addresses within a file don't change regardless of where the program is loaded**, the code can locate the GOT with a relative address, load the address of the GOT into a register, and then load pointers from the GOT whenever it needs to address static data. [my emphasis]

So indeed the relative addresses *inside* an ELF file are known when that file is being linked, and relocation for symbols in the same file (such as the GOT) can be resolved then.

Answer (score 2):

> The .so can't know where in memory it will actually be loaded though,

Correct.

> so I assume the addresses in readelfs section headers are just suggestions.

Incorrect.

After the static link, addresses of section headers are fixed and will remain exactly where they are (relative to each other). However note that section headers are not necessary at runtime and can be removed (e.g. via the `strip` command) -- nothing at runtime pays any attention to them.

> But since the distance to the GOT entry (mov rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ed0]) is hard coded, I assume the distances between the segments of the .so will always be as specified in the program headers?

Correct. All (loadable) segments are loaded together. That is, the loader cmputes how much space *all* the load segments need, then performs a single `mmap(0, ...)`<sup>1</sup>. The result of that `mmap` (the load base of this `.so`) is what determines where *all* segments from this `.so` are located.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming non-prelinked `.so`.

Comment: Thanks! How can it do a single `mmap`, when different segments need different flags? And I guess only the read only segments can be mmapped, for instance the segments containing `.got`, `.data`, `.bss` etc have to be unique per process?